# how to send xml request via post and receive xml response using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to connect to the URL specified and logging in with the credentials in login.xml file and getting the response in xml

[image: Code]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Be sure to describe the issue in the question - what is wrong with the current code? It's also preferable to paste the text of your code rather than sharing an image.

Comment: Please do not show code as an image. Do you really suppose that anybody will manually type the code into some development system when he tries to reproduce the problem?